# why my variable is always null when i send data using ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm gonna try to explain this good as i could. My variable in action.php  is always null when i submit a data via ajax btw i'm trying to edit my data using modal. i just don't know where did i go wrong i hope you guys got my point.
here is my code...

//html form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit Fields</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="form_data">
                    <form id="edit_data">
                        <input type="text" name="id" id="id2">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username2" class="form-control"><br>
                        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject2" class="form-control"><br>
                        <input type="text" name="plan" id="plan2" class="form-control"><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="go_edit" value="Edit" id="edit2" class="btn btn-warning">
                    </form>
                </form>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

// here is the ajax script

```
$('#edit2').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var edit = $("#edit_data").serialize() + "&go_edit=1";
            $.ajax({
                url:"action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:edit,
                success:function(data2){
                alert(data2);
                $('#exampleModalLong').modal('hide');
                $('#list').load(window.loccation = ' #list');
                }
                });

            });
        });
```

// php code to edit the data from the form located in action.php

```
if(isset($_POST['go_edit'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $plan = $_POST['plan'];
    var_dump($where = array("id" => $id));
    var_dump($myArray = array("username" => $username,
                    "subject" => $subject,
                    "plan" => $plan));
    if($data->EditData("new_users",$myArray,$where)){

        echo "Data Edited Successfully";
    }
}
```

// here is the sql for my edit located in action.php

```
public function EditData($table,$fields,$where){
            $sql = "";
            $condition = "";

            foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
                $condition .= $key ."='". $value. "' AND ";
            }
            $condition = substr($condition, 0, -5);

            foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
                $sql .= $key . "='".$value."', ";
            }
            $sql = substr($sql, 0, -2);
            $sql = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ".$sql." WHERE ".$condition;

            $query = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);

            if($query){
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Why do you have nested forms?

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injections! Don't do that

Comment: `if($data->EditData("new_users",$myArray,$where)){` - $data is not defined

Comment: Try to print the output of $("#edit_data").serialize() in browser console by console.log($("#edit_data").serialize()).

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer this is just a practice, i'm not planing to host this. anyway thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @Cashbee $data = new operation; is defined. it's just that i didn't include it on my post sorry

Answer (score 0):

Some modification to your jQuery code:
Get all the values:

```
var id1 = $("#id2").val();
var un1 = $("#username2").val();
var s1 = $("#subject2").val();
var p1= $("#plan2").val();
var submit=$('#edit2').val();
```

Async call to the PHP code with data:

```
$.post("action.php", {
 id: id1,
 username: un1,
 subject: s1,
 plan: p1,
 go_edit:submit
},function(data) {
$("#returnmessage").append(data); // Append returned message to message
if (data == "TRUE") {
   $("#form")[1].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
}
```